# How to get the android APK installation progress?

Tags: c#, android

I am using Android Tool "adb.exe" to install apk files to android phone.
The code is: `abd.exe install xxx.apk`

I want to use a C# progressBar to show the progress of installation. How can I get the progress?

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling adb.exe from a C# program, your options are limited, but what you're looking for is possible. If you redirect the standard output of the process, you should be able to observe the [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event and associate the output of adb with values of your progress bar.

Comment: It won't be granular at all - on my machine (with an outdated adb running), I get about six lines of text, but it's something.